# Play Store App publishing without a webserver

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

I've been notified by Google, that I need to submit a "Data safety" form for my Apps soon. The deadline is April 2022. However, the "Data safety" form cannot be submitted without a privacy policy. The only way to add a privacy policy in turn is to enter a URL.

Do I correctly deduce from this, that it'll soon be a requirement for a Play Store App developer to maintain a webserver?

Naturally, I'd like to avoid maintaining a web presence, because that'll cost me money. What are my options?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I understand the rationale of the accepted answer. Unfortunately, Googles Customer Service is virtually non-existent (algorithms answering with loosely fitting text blocks, is my impression). My primary concern is to get an answer though. And I think that many developers might face this exact same problem soon and will profit from the answers given here.

Comment: There are many other places to get answers to questions (e.g., Reddit) that do not have SO's rules for what is and is not on-topic. Your objective of getting an answer is perfectly reasonable; this is just not the site for it.

Comment: You can literally add any kind of URL there. Just upload something to Google Drive, set the file to public and use the public link.

Comment: @user1785730 was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [this tool](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) to generate privacy policy easily for your app.
2. then it will direct you to [flycricket](https://flycricket.com/) which provide free privacy policy hosting for your app (if you already have a privacy policy skip step 1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really acknowledged in the area of creating and maintaining an application; nevertheless, I believe I can help you with this one.

Basically, I believe that Google's intention is to have this information (the privacy policy in this case) findable in many different ways that are not only through the app exclusively. Hence, you could find the privacy policy and other policies as well online (like you can do for most apps you have on your devices).

As solutions for not having to manage and invest in a website, you were never asked to maintain a high-end one and pay for it — this is totally up to you I'd say. Obviously going for a better-looking website demonstrates how much you pay attention to your users, but it is surely not a have-to. Therefore, there'll always be free-to-use, even though limited, platforms that you can host a site in less than 5 minutes (such as WIX, for example).

I apologize if my answer was not as acknowledged as possible, but I'm just getting started in this world of coding and I still have a lot to learn.

Keep going with your great work, and good luck with your app!